# java applet export a jar file as an standalone executable

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet

I've been looking around for the solution but no one can solve the question I have.

I have an applet created by using eclipse and I would like to export it as a jar file so that others can use it easily.

The way I used for generating .jar file is in the following steps:

```
right click the project --> select export --> select JAR file --> next....
```

The jar file can be generated, however, when I use the command line to execute this jar

```
java -jar xxxx.jar
```

I got the error

```
no main manifest attribute, in test.jar
```

in the applet, I have no

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

while it should start with init().

And from what I've found so far, it seems like I have to add a manifest myself.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: An applet isn't meant to be executed outside of the context of a applet container (like a web browser). If you want other people to run your application, you should reconsider using a `JFrame` or similar instead of a applet. Take a closer look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the reply. I assume that the jar file could run as a standalone application since most of computers have java runtime on their environment.

Comment: @PathumAnjana thanks. let me take a look the link you provided.

Comment: @PathumAnjanai I've just gone through the link. However, in my source, I dont have "public static void main(String[] args)" in my code since applet supposes to start with init() function.

Comment: Yes, but an applet is a "runnable" program in the context of a desktop, its suppose to be run within an applet container.  A Java "application" on the hand is a different beast, take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) for starters

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for letting me know this. So if I would like to get my application as an standalone application, i need to use jframe instead (that means, the user can simply double click the jar file and execute the jar), is this correct?

Comment: So long as your setup the `main-class` entry in the manifest, yes, see [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks. I think you are correct and now I know it will not work as a standalone executable. It will be great if you post your answer to the answer blank so that i can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets are expected to run within an applet container, which is commonly supported by browsers (and the applet plugin).  You can't run them from the command line, at least not without modifying the code to support a window based solution.

Take a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for details about creating a desktop based application
- [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) for more details about the `main` method
- [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for details about how to make the Jar executable (you will still need a `main` method to make this work)